# Synchronise local folder and remote repository once again

Tags: git, github

I have a local folder with git and its corresponding remote git repository. They were well synchronised 1 week ago. Since then, I have made some changes in my local folder (but committed nothing), and my colleagues have added new commits to the remote repository (within the same branch).

I would like to know the standard process and git commands for the following two cases.

1) I want to check out the conflicts and merge my local change and the current remote repository, so that they are synchronised once again.

2) I want to give up all my local change, and just update my local folder with the newest version of the remote repository.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the remote is `origin`, and the branch is `master`.

---

> I want to check out the conflicts and merge my local change and the current remote repository, so that they are synchronised once again.

1. Commit your changes

```
$ git add <files-to-add>
$ git commit
```

2. Pull from remote repository

```
$ git pull origin master
```

3. Fix merge conflicts if any
4. Commit again with merge conflicts fixed

```
$ git add <files-with-conflict>
$ git commit
```

5. Push to remote repository

```
$ git push origin master
```

---

> I want to give up all my local change, and just update my local folder with the newest version of the remote repository.

1. Stash or reset your changes

```
$ git reset --hard
```

or (in case you want to apply your local changes again)

```
$ git stash
```

2. Pull from remote repository

```
$ git pull origin master
```